# Perforce client (p4) error when explicit port option not provided

Tags: linux, ubuntu, perforce

Trying to use perforce cli client (p4) to retrieve files from repository. I have a P4CONFIG=~/.p4config file configured with appropriate values.

When I try using the p4 command, I get the following error:

```
p4 login
Perforce client error:
    Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
    TCP connect to "ssl:fqdn.com:port" failed.
    Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

When I specify the p4 port (P4PORT), the command works:

```
p4 -p ${P4PORT} login
```

Note that perforce provides additional options that provide additional debug information:

```
p4 -p ${P4PORT} -vnet=5 -vrpc=5 login
```

Comment: It sounds like your `P4CONFIG` file contains an incorrect `P4PORT` value.  I suggest including the (unaltered) output of `p4 set P4PORT` and `p4 -p ${P4PORT} info` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the values in your P4PORT environment variable.

```
echo ${P4PORT}
echo ${P4PORT} | od -c
grep P4PORT ~/.bashrc
```

Also examine the value perforce examines in your perforce config,

```
grep P4PORT ${P4CONFIG}
grep P4PORT ${P4CONFIG} | od -c
p4 set P4PORT
```

The problem was that the P4PORT value in the configuration file had quotes. The shell strips quotes, but (apparently) perforce does not strip quotes in the config file.